# How do I find the unique id of each pages?

Tags: puppeteer

I need to save the id of each pages for some reason but I googled a lot did not find a working way to get the id of each pages.

Here is the code I tried to get the targetId as unique id of each pages, but it dont working in my version of puppeteer

```
const uniqueIdOfThePage = page._client._targetId
console.log(`The uniqueIdOfThePage is ${uniqueIdOfThePage}`)
```

After the code run the output is `undefined`

Here is the version of my puppeteer `^16.1.0`

actually I just need to save hole page instead of unique id of page but I dont want to do that because I think there must be a `string` represent the unique id of each page

Does anyone know how to find sort of representation of unique id of each page ?

Comment: Can you further clarify what you mean by Unique ID? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3):

Well, I found a way to get the "Unique id" of each page.
Here is the code:

```
const uniqueIdOfThePage = page.mainFrame()._id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I got nother way to do so.
First of all make sure always open new page from same function
And then just add a property to the page object like `uniqueId`
and then add a function for get the unique id of the page
Here is the code

```
async function newPage(browser) {
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    page.uniqueId = Date.now()
    let currentScreen = await page.evaluate(() => {
        return {
            width: window.screen.availWidth,
            height: window.screen.availHeight,
            deviceScaleFactor: 3
        };
    });

    // await installMouseHelper(page)
    await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(10000);
    await page.setViewport(currentScreen);
    await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.79 Safari/537.36')
    return page;
}
```

Here is the function for retrive the uniqueId

```
async function getPageUniqueId(page) {
    const uniqueId = page.uniqueId;
    if(!uniqueId) {
        console.error(`No uniqueId was assigned to the page please call the newPage() function for open new page`)
        throw new Error('No uniqueId was assigned to the page')
    }else {
        return uniqueId
    }
}
```